# Insert div above all other content on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have this JS, which is injected into foreign pages using a Chrome Extension. The following code adds a div element as the first child of the body element:

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'suman-per-tab-controls';
div.innerHTML = '<b>foooooo</b>';
document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
```

I also tried:

```
document.body.prepend(div);
```

With the following screenshot in mind:

[image]

If you look at the screenshot of the Quora website, you will notice that the div that I created is hidden behind their header.

**I am assuming that the only way to get my div above the Quora is CSS? Does anyone know of some handy CSS that nearly always if not always put a div above any existing content on a page?**

Comment: Try `position: fixed; z-index: 99999;`

Comment: It depends on the other CSS on the page. In the case of Quora they have a fixed header.

Comment: z-index brings it to the front, so I can now see my content...but I cannot push down their content, yet...so what will happen is my content will overlap with theirs as it stands.

Comment: If thats the case use CSS to add `top: 30px` to the header wrapper of the Quora header so it's not underneath your fixed position div. note: 30px is just a random number, you'll have to figure out how much you should really add.

Comment: @Jesse thanks, do you know of a good heuristic to locate the topmost element on the page, so I can add the CSS you mentioned to it?

Answer (score 1):

Try please following codes inside your css file,

```
   .suman-per-tab-controls {
        position: absolute;
        z-index:9999;
    }
```

or

```
   .suman-per-tab-controls {
       position: fixed;
       z-index:9999;
   }
```

or

```
   .suman-per-tab-controls {
       position: relative;
       z-index:9999;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the Quora navigation bar. and change it position property from fixed to relative.

[image: Here is the class for the navigation bar name ".SiteHeader"]

change position fixed to relative. Then you will see your newly added div.

Comment: upvoted, but I have to do this programmatically, I have to do it for 1000s of different websites, not just Quora, it has to be generic

Comment: Are you loading the websites inside an iframe? if so add the margin to the iframe?